# Load external images to lightbox plugin at Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, lightbox2

I face a problem which is related with Lightbox plugin at Wordpress, which is as follows:
When I load images to Lightbox, from the server in which my site is located everything works fine, but when I load images from an external site, instead of a popup with the particular image, I get a redirected image to the site it belongs. Is there a way to display these images also with Lightbox?? I searched a lot on web but I didn't find something useful..

Comment: check if lightbox allow to load ajax content. Bring your image using ajax.

Comment: I will check it but I will prefer not to make it to complex,because it's not pure code but it's done through Wordpress CMS. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you can view the images from your site then something else is awry. Generally a lightbox (which one? colorbor...) out-of-the-box setup just display what's loaded on your page. does the other site require ajax calls to hot link images?

Comment: You are right something else is going on... The problem isn't the external images, because at internal pages everything works fine,except from home page... I disabled all plugins to check if one of them causes the issue only in index but nothing changed..